# IOS, Delete data from firebase database when swipe to delete a cell

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is on ios

I am trying to delete data from the firebase database, when i swipe to delete a cell from tableview. the code below will delete all the posts data instead of the data i want to delete from only one cell in that table.

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: 
    UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {

        self.postData.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        Database.database().reference().child("Posts").removeValue()

}
```

}

Comment: You have to go one step deeper(postsId) to delete the selected post data. Please attach the screenshot of your firebase structure.

Answer (score 1):

You have to delete with post id

```
let postID = // set id
Database.database().reference().child("Posts").child("\(postID)").removeValue()
```

Comment: i do i set the table ids?

Comment: but you remove reference to the whole table in firebase you have to select the child corresponding to the cell index

Comment: i have it auto id everything under posts, so as the table refreshes on the ios app it list everything on my table, when i want to delete a cell i want that particular cell in the database to delete.

Comment: When you fetch the data from firebase parse the postId key for every post and init every object in the model array with it so you can access it with indexPath.row , and delete the corresponding post

Answer (score 1):

First save the id of post in the post model ,
you can get the key (id) of any object by

```
let postID = postSnapshot.key  //if you looping the array of snapshot
```

after that you can get the same post ID in tableView Delegate method

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: 
UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
if editingStyle == .delete {
    let postID = postData[indexPath.row].postKey //Assuming that you saving postID as a string.

    self.postData.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    Database.database().reference().child("Posts").child(postID).removeValue()
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
use like this 
   **to set like this**
    self.postkey.append(snapshot.key)
```

then

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle:
    UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        let postID =  self.postkey.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        self.myList.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        self.myTableView.reloadData()
        Database.database().reference().child("List").child(postID).removeValue()
    }
}
```